# How to write this method in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I just started Objective-C recently, and this has once again gotten me to the point of asking SO for help. I need to rewrite this method so that I can call it using [self URLEncodedString];

This is what the method currently looks like -

```
- (NSString *)URLEncodedString {
      NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)self, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
      [result autorelease];
      return result;
}
```

But I can't call it like [self URLEncodedString]; How can I rewrite it so that it would work for me to be able to call it using [self URLEncodedString];?

P.S. Calling it via [strValue URLEncodedString]; doesn't work, hence the reason I'm making this post.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This looks like a fine method implementation to me. This calls for more context/error message.

Comment: Do you have the signature of the message declared on the interface file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is to create an `NSString` category which will encode your string.

You need to create a new set of files, name them something that makes sense (NSString+URLEncoding).

In the .h file, you'll need something like this:

```
@interface NSString (URLEncoding)
- (NSString*)URLEncodedString;
@end
```

Then in your .m file:

```
@implementation NSString (URLEncoding)

- (NSString *)URLEncodedString {
      NSString *result = (NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)self, NULL, CFSTR("!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
      [result autorelease];
      return result;
}

@end
```

When you want to use this method, you'll need to make sure you import "NSString+URLEncoding.h".

You can then do something like this:

```
NSString * firstString = @"Some string to be encoded %&^(&(!@£$%^&*";
NSString * encodedString = [firstString URLEncodedString];
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the NSString instance method `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`?